# What were the "flap pump" and "gear pump" on the F-4E Phantom II?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, aircraft-systems, f-4

When I choose the F-4 in [X-Plane 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Plane_(simulator)) there are "buttons" labeled "flap pump" and "gear pump", whose tooltips say something like:

> Manually operating and closing flaps/pumps in a failure

So

1. How did pilots operate these hand pumps? Video is appreciated.
2. How much "pumping" was needed to open and close the landing gear?
3. How much "pumping" was needed to move flaps a single unit?
4. Did you need to be powerful in order to operate these hand pumps?
5. How did these pumps work?

Comment: Maybe somebody has a manual that can answer, I know it can be quite a few pumps. For example, the manual gear lowering pump in a 177-RG is 40 strokes.

Comment: Hmm, I just read the entire RF-4B manual and there are no such buttons/switches in it. The emergency procedures for both flaps and gear involve activating high pressure systems, not pumps. Continuing to research, but this _may_ be an anachronism to the game.

Comment: The F-4J manual is the same. No such switches exist. I would also point out that in both manuals, in the event of a flap failure, or gear failure, the emergency systems are designed to _deploy_ the flaps and gear. Re-retracting both systems after emergency deployment is contra-indicated and said to be impossible.

Comment: How can this question be too broad? It is about one plane, and two switches.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Flap Pump" or "Gear pump". There is a hydraulic system on the F4 though. All those systems need hydraulic power. They run on hydraulics.